# Assign item to specific artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I have two artboards. I'm having issues assigning this thing to artboard 1 as it's assigned to artboard 2. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: @Scott I'm not trying to align anything. I just want to assign that object to artboard 1 to properly move the whole artboard around alongside its layers.

Comment: The problem is there really isnt any such thing as a arboard assignment. The artboard is only an area. Items certainly can span multiple areas and areas certainly can overlap. Once they do you get into mental gymnastics problems like this due to features added to those artboards later but the system below does not know anything about stuff like this. Therefore having art boards that have overlappling objects gets you confusing situations.

Comment: Apologies.. I read "assign" as "align". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select the object(s)
- Choose `Edit > Cut`
- Click Artboard 1 with the **Selection Tool** (black arrow) You *should* see the artboard edge get darker, indicating it's the *active* artboard.
- Choose `Edit > Paste in Front` (or back)

The pasted object(s) *should* be in the same location, but now associated with Artboard 1.

Sometimes when pasting objects between artboards there's some underlying voodoo which takes place and the paste coordinates are "hinky". Objects which *should* paste in the same location somehow use coordinates from their *previous* artboard. When that happens, it becomes necessary to reposition the pasted object(s) manually.

Comment: Thank you so much!